# Mock ASP.Net User in WebForms app

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I have a legacy app that I am trying to build some testing into.

I have some tests that require the HttpContext.Current.User

Is there a way to mock this, or simply login a user on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.User` is of type `IPrincipal`. You can mock it by assigning to it any `IPrincipal` object, including any `CustomPrincipal` object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't now how much you can refactor your legacy application.  If you have .NET 3.5, you can use HttpContextWrapper class that is part of System.Web.Abstraction assembly.

You can read more and see an example how to [Stub/Mock HttpContext](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/stub-htttpcontext/).